# Count values greater than in another dataframe based on values in existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have two python pandas dataframes, in simplified form they look like this:

DF1

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| a_1 | a_2 | a_3 | a_4 | a_5 | a_6 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   0 |   2 |   5 |   0 |   2 |   5 |
|   1 |   3 |   4 |   1 |   3 |   4 |
|   1 |   0 |   3 |   0 |   0 |   1 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

DF2

```
+-----+
|   A | 
+-----+
| a_1 | 
| a_2 | 
| a_3 |
| a_4 | 
| a_5 | 
| a_6 | 
+-----+
```

I want to create a count column of values (per row) in DF2, if each of the value in column A (DF2) equals to column names in DF1 then count number greater than zero in selected column

Desire output:

```
+-----+-------+
|   A | Count | 
+-----+-------+
| a_1 |   2   |  
| a_2 |   2   | 
| a_3 |   3   | 
| a_4 |   1   | 
| a_5 |   2   | 
| a_6 |   3   | 
+-----+-------+
```

Appreciate any comment and feedback, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with compared values in `DF1` by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
DF2['Count'] = DF2['A'].map(DF1.gt(0).sum())
print (DF2)
     A  Count
0  a_1      2
1  a_2      2
2  a_3      3
3  a_4      1
4  a_5      2
5  a_6      3
```